# Is it possible to do remote capture on a Canon DSLR?

Tags: remote, tethering

Is it possible to do remote capture on a Canon EOS DSLR?  I have an infra-red remote, but when I connect the camera to the PC via USB I only get the option to download pictures from it.

I'm a pretty proficient Windows user, currently on XP, Vista or Win7 depending on which machine I use.  The laptop is Win7, so any information with a bias in that direction would be most appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on Windows, then you'd use the "EOS Utility" application (which you [can download from Canon](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0037078.asp?model=) if you haven't already got it).

This application supports:

- Functions for downloading and displaying images
- **Remote shooting**, and camera control of each setting when an EOS DIGITAL camera is connected to a computer

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, if you use Windows or Mac OS-X, then you can use the EOS Capture utility which is part of Canon Digital Photo Professional (DPP) - You can install this from one of the disks that came with your camera, and then update it from [here](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/software/dpp/).

An alternative, if you're a Lightroom 3 user, would be to do the tethered capture from within Lr itself, since [the EOS 400D is a supported camera](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/842/cpsid_84221.html).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux or MacOS, you could try using [gphoto2](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/), which definitely supports the 400D.

See, for instance, [this guide to creating timelapse movies using gphoto2](http://www.moreno.marzolla.name/software/time_lapse_movies/)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the evaluation copy of [DSLR Remote](http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/) on two different still projects and it's really great. A simple but functional application.